# Rotation of a cylinder around its vertical axis

Tags: plotting, animation

I want that that cylinder plotted by

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[t], u}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, -10, 0.02}]
```

to rotate around its vertical axis. If possible I want to use `Animate[Rotate[]]` command, because I'm not very expert.
I will give that cylinder a texture, this way I will be able to see its rotation around the z axis.

Comment: Which axis in your mind is the "vertical" axis? In my mind, for the cylinder your code produces, it the z-axis of the coordinate system. But rotating about that axis will produce no visual change in the plot, because the cylinder is rotationally symmetrical about that axis. Please clarify your intent.

Comment: The axis I want to indicate Is the axis you're intending, I will give the cylinder a texture to make that rotation visible...

Comment: You should not omit such important information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RevolutionPlot3D` will distort the texture badly. Things will look much better if you use `ParametricPlot3D`. Here is an example.

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[t], u}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, -10, 0.02},
  PlotStyle -> Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]],
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Mesh -> None,
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> None,
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2},
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    ViewPoint -> {100 Cos[θ], 100 Sin[θ], -5}],
  {θ, 4. π/3, 10. π/3, 2. π/12},
  Deployed -> True,
  DefaultDuration -> 30]
```

[image: lena]

Note that the animation actually rotates the camera's position (the view point) around a fixed cylinder rather than rotating the cylinder while keeping the camera fixed. It is really easier to do this by rotating the camera.

Comment: Very cool bro :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the cylinder from different directions:

```
 Animate[
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], h}, 
         {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {h, 0, 5},
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    ViewPoint -> {2 Cos[\[Phi]], 2 Sin[\[Phi]], 3}],
 {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}]
```

Comment: It's possible to do a similiar thing with "ParametricPlot3D" command? It's easier to give a texture to the object in a "Plot" command...

Answer (score 0):

You can also `RotateRight` the `Texture` image to get the same visual effect:

```
im = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
dim = ImageDimensions[im][[1]];
imdt = ImageData@im;

Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[t], u}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, -10, 0.02}, 
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Yellow, Texture[Image[RotateRight[#, r] & /@ imdt]]], 
  SphericalRegion -> True, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None,
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, Lighting -> "Neutral", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
{r, 0, dim, 1}]
```

[image]